# Grouping like errors from Loki ineffective due to variables

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

I have a Grafana dashboard that includes a panel which groups like error messages from Loki to display the most common errors. However, I get a lot of like messages that are not grouped due to variable data. For example:
"User ID **'123456'** is of a type that is not found in the DB".
If this error occurs for 50 users, I want to report it as 50 occurrences of the same error but instead, it shows it as 50 separate errors because the User ID is unique for each.

- Is there a way to have Grafana recognize the pattern but ignore the dissimilar portion?
- Is there a way to structure the LogQL query to ignore text within single quotes?

My current LogQL query is:

```
topk(10, sum(count_over_time({cluster=~"${cluster:regex}", namespace=~"${namespace:regex}"} [$__range] | json | __error__ = "" ) ) by (MessageTemplate))
```

Comment: *"Is there a way to structure the LogQL query to ignore text within single quotes?"*: you can try something like this ``| label_format MessageTemplate=`{{regexReplaceAll "'[^']+'" .MessageTemplate "'placeholder'"}}` ``